# Losing focus on TLF Text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have embedded my SWF file to an HTML. I am using a TLF text in my AS3 application for the chatbox, but the problem is that the application loses its focus on TLF text while I switch to other pages, and switch back on my application. Please note that I do not face this problem while I run the SWF file using flash player on my desktop.

I have tried to use following code to re-focus on the TLF text but it does not work on my case.

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, infocus);
function infocus(e:Event):void {
    myTLF.textFlow.interactionManager = new EditManager();
    myTLF.textFlow.interactionManager.selectRange(myTLF.text.length, myTLF.text.length);
    myTLF.textFlow.interactionManager.setFocus();
}
```

My question is how we can resolve this? because it really bothers people since they have to click on the chatbox every times that they switch to other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to do so. You can manually put focus on your desired objects either by:

- listening to MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER on your stage make a handler that will return the focus to your text field
- if you want to make it to return focus on switch back to the page, you'll need to write a JS script that will tell SWF via ExternalInterface to put focus on your text field.